# PHP app.yaml, new to GAE, not sure of how to setup

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a single page website built on bootstrap 3, that I am trying to move to Google Apps Engine.  I Scaffold my sites using php, and all the content is showing but not the styles and javascript.  My site is basically set up as follows

- _/js/bootstrap.js
- _/js/custom.js
- _/fonts/glypicon ...etc
- _/css/bootstrap.css
- _/css/custom.css
- _/php/ .. all my php files go here ...
- index.php

can someone help me setup my app.yaml for this? I am new to GAE, and am a little confused by this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

Comment: what is _/ ? Is this a directory?

Comment: Yes _/ is a directory, I use it so it is always listed at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

```
application: myapp     # of course, replace with your app name
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /index\.html
  script: index.php

- url: /_/css
  static_dir: _/css

- url: /_/js
  static_dir: _/js

- url: /_/fonts
  static_dir: _/fonts

- url: /images/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: images/\1    # assuming you put your images in a directory called 'images'
  upload: images/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /.*
  script: not_found.php    # if not_found.php (custom 404 handler) exists.  otherwise, just serve index.php
```

Comment: images are in a folder called images/ in the root, not static, so i updated that in the file.  But I am still seeing the same results in the browser.

Comment: Can you navigate directly to: http://www.yoursite.com/js/bootstrap.js?  Can you paste your html code calling for the js and css files?

Comment: I am running it through the SDK at localhost:8080, I have tried going directly to the image with http://localhost:8080/images/photo.jpg and it sends me to the not_found.php. I will try the js and CSS files when I'm back in front of my computer.

Comment: The code I posted has you specify the images at the root url.  If your url uses /images/..., see edit I just added to code.

Comment: Images are now showing, but still no css or js.
<link href="_/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="_/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="_/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="_/js/custom.js"></script>

Comment: I did not realize the _/ was part of the url.  Code edited.  You should get the idea now, to match the urls to your directories.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the idea, thanks so much, it is working like it should now.  You rock man!

Comment: Deployed today, and my images do not show up, the background images in the CSS do but the others do not

Comment: I may have found the answer to my own problem.  All my image names have spaces in them ie. 1234 - this product.jpg ,  don't think this is supported